# how to set different background color of different screens - Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I'm creating two different themes black and white. In one of the themes, Its completely black background. But in other theme, I am going to use two different background colors for two different screens (layouts).
For example, first screen red color and second, and third are white colors.
I'm stuck there. Please help me to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could You show some code?

Answer (score 1):

Define several themes with `android:windowBackground` set to the different colors and then call `setTheme()` in your activity's `onCreate()`. These themes can inherit from your main app theme.

Answer (score 0):

There should be different XML files for different pages/screens. These can be found in `res -> layout`. After opening the XML file you want, click on the "Graphical Layout" tab. Then click on the page. Then you will see a list of settings/properties for the layout, the bottom left of the screen. From here you can change whatever you want :)